# Open Dired for an arbitrary set of files

Tags: dired, navigation, directory, ranger

There is a project with 100 files in a flat directory.
I want to navigate a subset of the files, depending on what part of the project I am working on.
Creating files with links to files of interest would do the job.  For example,
To navigate alphabet files of project, open alphabet.org:

```
file:fA.cpp
file:fB.cpp
file:fC.cpp
```

To navigate number files of project, open numbers.org:

```
file:f1.cpp
file:f2.cpp
file:f3.cpp
```

Does Dired or Ranger have a similar functionality?

This might be what Lorefnon is describing, but I don't know enough Emacs to understand it:
quote from https://lorefnon.me/2015/11/15/utilities-for-efficient-filesystem-navigation-in-emacs.html

> Dired buffers can be bookmarked just like ordinary buffers and we can
>   use bookmark-jump to quickly jump to important Dired buffers opened
>   before

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy; but haven't learned Dired or Ranger yet.

**UPDATE**

I went with Drew's Dired+ and it works well.  It lets you open Dired for an arbitrary set of files.

On Spacemacs, add dired+ to your dotspacemacs-additional-packages list.

From diredp-dired-plus-help:

```
C-x D A      Add files to a Dired buffer.
             You are prompted for the Dired buffer name and for each file or dir to include.
```

Usage with Spacemacs:

```
SPC f c      (spacemacs/copy-file) Write the file under new name.
             Saves Dired buffer to a file.
SPC f s      (save-buffer) Save current buffer in visited file if modified.
             Does not save Dired buffer to file unless it's a visited file.
```

Comment: I've never done this but you can look at projectile. Maybe you can create multiple projects and switch projectile projects based on organizational preferences. Then use `projectile-switch-project` and `projectile-find-file`

Comment: Please write a more informative question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but perhaps this will help. Offhand, a guess is that bookmarking Dired buffers is close to what you are looking for.

1. **Dired** itself lets you have a Dired buffer that contains (only) a given set of files and directories - from anywhere in your file system. You do this by passing a list of them to function `dired`.  See `C-h f dired`.
2. You can *mark* a set of files and subdirs in a Dired buffer, and then act on them in arbitrary or predefined ways.  Such a set of marked files can represent the files in a given project, for instance.
3. You can *hide* the marked files and subdirs in Dired.  This can give you a "project" view of a larger set of files.
4. [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) can make these Dired things easier. It also lets you easily combine arbitrary Dired listings (e.g. subprojects) and otherwise add to Dired listings, search, including recursively, and more.
5. If you use library [**Bookmark+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can *bookmark* Dired buffers, and return to them later. Bookmarking records all markings, which files are hidden, etc. So after configuring a given Dired buffer the way you want, to represent the files and dirs of a project, for example, you can bookmark that configured state - and restore it later just by "jumping" to that bookmark. You can have any number of bookmarks to the same Dired buffer, representing different views of it - different subsets etc.
6. Bookmark+ also provides many other ways to support defining and managing projects as sets of files. Just search for "project" [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus), to get an idea.
7. Library [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) also provides various kinds of [support for projects](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects)

Comment: Thanks Drew.  I don't completely understand, but it sounds good enough for me to learn Dired and Bookmark, and maybe Dired+ and Bookrmark+.  If it works I will accept your answer, but it may take me a few days.

Comment: I'm sure you will get other suggestions here. There is no hurry to try or decide on this or that. Get acquainted with various ways to organize files etc. Also, this question is a bit broad, because at this point you are looking for ideas about what is available. Future, more-specific questions will likely get more (specifically) helpful answers.

Comment: How to install Dired+?  M-x diredp-dired-plus-help is not on my Spacemacs.  And there are no install instructions on https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus

Comment: Found the Dired+ install instructions on http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Dired%2B , the installer then said:
      Status: Available Obsolete from melpa -- Install
    Archive: melpa

    Version: 20170818.1411

Comment: No idea what that means. I'd say maybe *ignore wikemacs.org* (which itself is obsolete, if I remember right). The latest of my libraries is always on Emacs Wiki, and from there it is mirrored automatically to MELPA. You should be able to get Dired+ from either [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el) or MELPA. In the latest you see this in the file header: "**Last-Updated: Fri Aug 18 14:10:39 2017 (-0700)**" and this: "**Update #: 10354**". The doc page, with a link to the source code, is [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

Comment: And if I do `M-x list-packages` I see this: "**  dired+  20170818.1411 available  melpa  Extensions to Dired.**". No idea where you're seeing an "installer" that says "Status: Available Obsolete from melpa". But even what you see seems to show the right version (date): "**20170818.1411**". I'm curious how you got that "Obsolete" bit.

Comment: "Installer" is probably the wrong word.  I was following the instructions on wikemacs.org.  Later I added dired+ to my dotspacemacs-additional-packages list, and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

> fA.cpp
>   fB.cpp
>   fC.cpp

No-frills approach in Dired:

- <kbd>%</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> `f[A-Z]\.cpp` <kbd>RET</kbd> to mark files
- <kbd>t</kbd> to invert the marks
- <kbd>k</kbd> to hide the marked files

Answer (score 1):

Install https://github.com/technomancy/find-file-in-project (available at http://melpa.org)

- `M-x find-file-in-current-directory` or `find-file-in-project-by-selected` or `find-file-in-project`
- you got interactive UI to filter candidates. The UI is based on ivy (https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper), so you could input `keyword1 keyword2` to tweak the final result (Please note space is converted to regex ".*" by ivy)
- Press `C-c C-o` to output the file list to a new buffer. Done!

Now you can press `ENTER` key on any item of that file list to open a file

BTW, ivy supports more advanced syntax (like negative pattern), for example `keyword1 !keyword2 keyword3` corresponds to `grep keyword1 | grep -v keyword2 | grep -v keyword3`

Other solutions:

- `M-x find-name-dired`, same backend (GNU Find) as `find-file-in-project` but UI is different
- `M-x find-lisp-find-dired`, pure lisp implementation. Slower but works out of box (If you use Emacs on Windows, this might be the only solution to search file name containing East Asian character).